# API Content-Type request header changes the Azure Function Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest body type

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

Consider you have an API Management instance, and an Azure Function exposed as an OpenAPI API (through: Add an API -> OpenAPI (not Function App))

Now if you read the bodies from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` in the Azure Function (by remote debugging), you get different types of Body streams depending on your Content-Type request header added at the API Management layer, so for example:

- Content-Type: `application/json` will get you: `System.IO.Stream {Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream}`
- Content-Type: `text/plain` will get you: `System.IO.Stream {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream}`
- Content-Type: `application/octet-stream` will get you: `System.IO.Stream {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream}`

The problem with the `WrappingStream` is that `CanSeek` is `false` and thus not usable in a few scenario's (for instance directly using it to pass the stream to blob storage).

I'm using the latest `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` version 3.0.9

Just wondering if this behavior is what we should expect, or if it's just weird behavior? I also doubt if this behaviour was always this way, as i got this working without correct content type a few weeks ago.

Comment: Who send the header to your functions? Can't you ask them to send the header that your functions expect?

Comment: Yes I've forced the correct header, but it feels like a workaround.